# Placing text from a database into a textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, database

I'm working on a WPF application and i cant seem to get this right. I am brand new to WPF.

I want to get the text from the database into text boxes but i tried it with only one textbox the first time and i get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

This is the code i have so far, this is how it's done in winforms but i suppose not the same in WPF

```
dbconn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=ChampInfo1.accdb");
dbconn.Open();
string selectallSQL = "SELECT Passive " +
                      "FROM BChampInfo " +
                      "WHERE [Champ Name] = Aatrox";
dbcomm = new OleDbCommand(selectallSQL, dbconn);

OleDbDataReader dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader();
while (dbread.Read())
{
     txtskillname1.Text = dbread["Passive"].ToString();
}
```

I don't know what is wrong though, any help will be appreciated.
All my oledb declaration are done at the top.

Comment: Try "WHERE [Champ Name] = 'Aatrox'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be the easy target for sql injection.  The problem is in query. Try this

```
        string selectallSQL = "SELECT Passive " +
                  "FROM BChampInfo " +
                  "WHERE [Champ Name] = ?";
dbcomm = new OleDbCommand(selectallSQL, dbconn);
    dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aat", "Aatrox");
```

Comment: Thanx, that works! But now, how come when I add more fields to select, it throws the error again? @ethicallogics

Comment: Why on Earth would you split the one-line query like this??